# Creating custom PROJ projection from control points

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, proj

I have a JPG raster, and I used QGis to georeference it with "control points", which are pixel coordinates linked to map coordinates, in EPSG:4326 (lon, lat).

Here is an example of the control points we can have from QGis from raster to EPSG:3857
[image]

I would like to create a custom projection system for this image, and generate the PROJ text line, in order to add it to PostGIS for example, and use this custom image projection like any other projection system.

I can't find any documentation on how to create PROJ parameters from a list of control points image coordinates / map coordinates. Do you have any idea of how to create these parameters?

Comment: When you georeference, you're basically forcing the data into the same coordinate reference system as the base/reference data.

Comment: What is the Transformation Type used?

Comment: @mkennedy What I would like to do is the reverse of the georeferencing operation, once the operation was made. Once the image had allowed generating these deformation vectors, create some kind of projection that will convert a point or a polygon from a know EPSG, to the reference system of the image (in pixels). For example, in the image reference : (0,0) would be the lower left corner.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca In this example, the transformation was Think plate spline (from QGis).

Comment: In image space, you have no linear resolution so analysis would be...difficult. The image represents geographic data. I think you should use a known geographic or projected coordinate reference system.